# Updating normalised data without causing more re-renders outside of the state slice that has been updated

Tags: redux

I have some normalised data (`items`) within my redux store:

```
{
  items: {
    index: ['a','b'],
    dict: {
      a: {
        title: "red",
      },
      b: {
        title: "car",
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

So, if I want to update anything within an item object, the reducer looks like this:

```
...
const itemsReducer = (state = initialState.items, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case itemsActions.types.UPDATE_ITEM: {
          return {
            ...state,
            [action.payload.itemId]: {
              title: action.payload.title,
            }
          }
        }

        default: return state;
    }
};
```

But this technique creates a new object for `items`, which can cause unnecessary components to re-render, when really it should only cause components that subscribe to state changes of the individual object to re-render.

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

That is how immutable updates are required to work - [you *must* create copies of *every* level of nesting that needs to be updated](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-nested-objects).

In general, [components should extract the smallest amount of data that they need from the store](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#using-multiple-selectors-in-a-component), to help minimize the chance of unnecessary re-renders.  For example, most of the time a component probably shouldn't be reading the entire `state.items` slice.

FWIW, it looks like you're hand-writing your reducer logic. You *should* be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) to write your Redux logic in general.  RTK also specifically has a [`createEntityAdapter` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter) that will do most typical normalized state updates for you, so you don't have to write reducer logic by hand.

I'll also note that the recently released [Reselect 4.1 version](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/releases/tag/v4.1.0) has new options you can use for customizing memoized selectors as well.

Comment: In the example where you have a component that generates a list of todos (items), where each todo is itself a component (item), updating the text of a single todo will cause the entire todo list to re-render. I need a way to target only the state slice that represents a single item without creating an entirely new items object.

Comment: That's why we generally recommend [having the parent component read item IDs from the store, passing the IDs to children as props, and having the children read their own data from the store by item ID](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#selecting-data-in-list-items-by-id).  Additionally, `createEntityAdapter` helps ensure that the `entityState.ids` array stays stable even if the item data changes, allowing the parent to avoid re-rendering when an item is updated as long as it selects that IDs list.

Comment: In other words, immutable updates require making new references all the way up the chain. That can't change. You need to switch the approach and alter how the UI is selecting the data instead.

Comment: I understand the concept for sure, just that when, for example, you have a 'completed' property in the item object that needs to be used to toggle the list view and include completed items in the list, id's just aren't enough (?)

Comment: Actually, just looking at the Redux Toolkit example `todoToggled(state, action) {
      const todoId = action.payload
      const todo = state.entities[todoId]
      todo.completed = !todo.completed
    },` it appears that individual properties like 'complete' can be updated directly. Is this only possible within `createSlice` or is this generally allowed, even when writing reducers manually?

Comment: You're kind of misunderstanding what that does. It's still an immutable update, with all the rules of "nested cloning" that must occur. It's just that Immer makes it easier to write that without all the nested spreads: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers . Assuming that value was at `state.todos.entities[5].completed`, it will still make copies of `entities[5]`, `entities`, `todos`, and the root `state`, exactly as if you had done all that by hand. It's just a shorter way to write it.